# Unable to access port 4200 in EC2 - aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an `EC2` machine on `ubuntu` server.

I have hosted my `node.js` application there.

I am able to access port `3000`. But not able to access port `4200`.

In my security group `4200` is added and also in `Inbound` rules it is showing.

Here is the image showing my security group:

[image]

[image]

What else do I need to check?

**Edit**

In Port 3000 my APIs are hosted. I am able to run those api by using Postman Client and even in the browser.

Comment: You can also check `NetworkACL Rules`, check running port on your server `netstat -alpn | grep 4200`, check iptable on server

Comment: and any other corporate/home firewalls.

Comment: @d1ll1nger How can I check firewalls?

Comment: That would be dependent on where you're connecting from and connection methods. For example, if you connect to AWS via VPN tunnels there's at least another 3 layers where connectivity can be blocked. If this is just a public facing instance and you're connecting direct from your home client, then it could just be your home router firewall... It's quite a broad question.

Comment: @d1ll1nger Got your point. So I need to check everywhere? Is their is no specific reason for this issue?

Comment: may sound silly, but are you sure the node app is listening on that port and not on 3000? On the server `curl http://localhost:4200`

Comment: @Daniel On Port 3000 my API is hosted. I am able to get and post data using postman client and even through the browser.

Comment: @Dalvik Is there anything listening on port 4200 ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem on my ec2 instance once which had node js , You need to have something listening to port 4200 in order for it to be open.

If you nothing listening to port 4200 even if your linux firewall is down and security group permits then also *when you test the port will refuse connection*.

Also What one of the best practice is that request to Node should be served via webserver like Apache or nginx and that (virtual host in case of apache) should be configured accordingly.

Hope it helps